# Env Variables in Python (v3.0) on Windows

Tags: python, windows, scripting, shell

I'm using Python 3.0.

How to expand an environment variable given the %var_name% syntax?

Any help is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in a slightly unexpected place: [os.path.expandvars()](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser). Admittedly it is quite often used for processing paths:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.expandvars('%APPDATA%\\MyApp')
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Application Data\\MyApp'
```

but it's a shell function really.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you mean "How do I get environment variables?":

```
import os
username = os.environ['UserName']
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
username = os.getenv('UserName')
```

And to add/change your own variables, you can use:

```
os.putenv('MyVar', 'something I want to store')
```